# polymophism of pointers

Tags: c++, constructor, polymorphism

I am using a `boost::ptr_vector`, but I believe this applies to a standard `std::vector` as well. I am trying to place pointers to objects polymophically into a `boost::ptr_vector` the hierarchy is that I have an `Entity` that inherits from `Object` being created with the line

```
Object * newObject = new Entity(param1, param2);  // then I attempt to add it to the ptr_vector
```

but if I break the program (Visual Studio 2010) to look at what is being held the pointer is never redirected from garbage, and garbage is being held. I step through the code, and it does enter the parameterized constructor, and follows the correct logical steps with it.

I am uncertain what is going wrong. do I need to have specific member functions in the parent, or the child in order for this polymorphic behavior to work (currently all children have parameterized constructors unique to their type, and destructors along with polymorphic interaction methods). must I have assignment operators, or should I have a constructor in the `Object` class.

It seems to be that the call to operator `new` is not resolving to an object, but resolving to something else, but VS2010 is not throwing an error.

---

Edit: explanation of what should be happening.

stepping through a 2D `std::vector`(rectangular/non-jagged)

using `case/switch` to determine object to be generated, and added to structure

pointer to Object is created, and assigned to new // I think this is where the problem is happening

then the reference of that pointer is pushed onto a manager-member `boost::ptr_vector`

in Visual Studio 2010 I put a break at the line to create the pointer, and assign new (polymorphic), and one on the line for the `push_back()` to the `boost::ptr_vector` watching the pointer. The temp pointer value is created, and stepping into the constructor it follows all logical steps for that constructor, and when the constructor finishes, and the stack returns to the line that called the constructor the pointer is still the same value (I think this is acceptable), but when I look at the object that it points to all the values show up as question marks (including the statically composed member objects). then when the push back triggers, and enters boost-header the `x` value show the same information.

it almost seems like the pointer is being made, and the datams of the object are created, but once the constructor is finished it doesn't actually assign the values to the parent class object which should be considerably simple with regards to polymophic behavior.

example headers of concern (the real headers do have member variables, and their implementations are in a separate cpp file):

```
class Object{
public :
    virtual void interact(int action, Object& source){}
    virtual void updateObject(float duration){}
    virtual ~Object(){}
    bool operator==(const Object& _other)const;
    bool operator!=(const Object& _other)const;
};

class Entity : public Object{
public:
    Entity(Vector3 location, Type thisType, SpecialType difficulty=noSpecial);
    ~Entity();
    void interact(int action, Object& source);
    void updateObject(float duration);
};
```

---

Edit: changing context to better target problem at hand, and receive a solution

Comment: can you show us how you are populating vector?

Comment: @naveen I don't think it has to do with populating the vector, but with actually getting the object that is being constructed, and assigned to the pointer in the first place

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but just in case… You are debugging a non-optimized debug build, right? Because in a release build, it's very likely that the compiler is going to skip all the intermediate copies, and just leave the pointer in some register and not store it anywhere in memory until the vector's storage. A debugger _could_ handle that by showing the contents of that register whenever you try to view newObject, x, etc., but it could just as easily handle it by showing garbage for those pointers, or refusing to show anything.

Comment: One more thing: What happens if you fprintf/syslogs/cerr/whatever newObject and/or newObject->someMember (if they're all private, temporarily make one public for the test) between the new and the push_back?

Comment: @abarnert VS2005+ gives the capability to see any "visible" data member in real time as each takes place, and even in the middle of complex operations, and when I do a `std::cout` on any of the members it triggers a memory dump which is what happens when `std::cout` is called on garbage data

Comment: Can you create a short, compilable example program that exhibits this behavior?  It does not have to be with the actual classes you use as long as the same behavior is observed.  So far what you are describing should not be happening, so it would be beneficial to experiment with actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you've posted, it's difficult (if even possible) to be sure of the problem, not to mention how it's coming about/how to fix it.

Perhaps it's better to start from something that actually works, and add the functionality you need, or at least get some idea of places you're deviating from what's expected/what works. So, here's a small sample of creating objects dynamically, putting them into a `ptr_vector`, using a virtual function in each to verify that what's in the container is what's expected, and then letting the container go out of scope (and in the process, destroying the objects referred to by the pointers it contains).

```
#include "boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

class Object { 
    std::string name;
public:
    Object(std::string const &n) : name(n) {}

    virtual std::ostream &write(std::ostream &os) const {
        return os << name;
    }

    virtual ~Object() { std::cout << "Object being destroyed\n"; }
};

class Entity : public Object { 
    int value;
public:
    Entity(int v, std::string name) : Object(name), value(v) {}

    std::ostream &write(std::ostream &os) const { 
        return os << "Entity: " << value;
    }
    ~Entity() { std::cout << "Entity being destroyed\n"; }  
};

int main() { 
    boost::ptr_vector<Object> objects;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        std::stringstream name;
        name << "object: " << i;
        if (i & 1)
            objects.push_back(new Object(name.str()));
        else
            objects.push_back(new Entity(i, name.str()));
    }

    boost::ptr_vector<Object>::iterator pos;
    for (pos = objects.begin(); pos != objects.end(); pos++) {
        pos->write(std::cout);
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

At least for me, the output looks like this:

```
Entity: 0
object: 1
Entity: 2
object: 3
Entity: 4
object: 5
Entity: 6
object: 7
Entity: 8
object: 9
Entity being destroyed
Object being destroyed
Object being destroyed
Entity being destroyed
Object being destroyed
Object being destroyed
Entity being destroyed
Object being destroyed
Object being destroyed
Entity being destroyed
Object being destroyed
Object being destroyed
Entity being destroyed
Object being destroyed
Object being destroyed
```

For what it's worth, note the destructors -- when an `Object` is destroyed, only the base dtor is invoked, but when an `Entity` is destroyed, first the derived dtor is invoked, then the base dtor is invoked (so we see both 'Entity being destroyed' and 'Object being destroyed").

Comment: I was treating the `ptr_vector` incorrectly by invoking it with `boost::prt_vector<Object*>` which made them always equal the last thing being put on, and when that pointer went out of scope the objects stopped existing hence garbage.

Answer (score 2):

After

```
Object * newObject = new Entity(param1, param2);
```

you will have `newObject` pointing to the freshly created object. While the constructor is
running, `newObject` is still not assigned. If you have afterwards e.g.

```
vec.push_back(newObject);
```

you can step into the `push_back` method and see the argument is an `Object` having
a virtual table referencing to `Entity` methods. (You have a virtual destructor at least,
right?)

Comment: yes I have a virtual destructor, and when I enter the `push_back()` the `x` shows the same garbage pointer value, and when I look at the values that the pointer points to it shows question marks even though my `Entity` constructor does assignment, and the `new` should create a pointer, and assign it to the pointer variable right?

Answer (score 1):

The pointer value only changes *after* the constructor has finished, it's not a problem. It's logical because first a temporary pointer is acted upon and only the it is assigned to your pointer.

Comment: but that reassignment is not happening its like the constructor is being called, and then the assignment is not happening